# Laptop Fan Speed Control

Tags: laptop, fan, temperature, fancontrol

Sometimes my laptop's fans are too loud but the laptop itself is at 30c so how can I change it so it ramps up higher when it is at higher temps.

Comment: How is it Ubuntu related?

Comment: I use ubuntu and need software/code that works in ubuntu.

Comment: In most cases you can't control fan speeds from an OS. It depends on hardware.

Comment: I don't know about this topic but I don't think you can control your fan speed as it depends on how hot is your laptop. You should probably let your fan make the noice or else your laptop will overheat

Comment: what type of laptop is it?  There are a few different utilities that help with fan control on laptops.  If the fans are running full speed in Ubuntu even when its not hot, then I would think the BIOS has handed off control of the fan to the OS.